# Send a signal when a USB serial cable is unplugged

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qt-signals, qtserialport

Is there a way to send a signal, or any other way to tell if a USB serial cable is unplugged, using Qt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `error` signal of the QSerialPort class in the QtSerialPort add-on. See the details for that in our documentation.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtserialport/qserialport.html#error-prop

You will need to write this basically:

```
connect(mySerialPort, SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)), this,
        SLOT(handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)));

...

void MyClass::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
{
    if (error == QSerialPort::ResourceError) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Critical Error"), serial->errorString());
        closeSerialPort();
    }
}
```

QtSerialPort can be installed easily with Qt 5.1 < as the packages are distributed. However, we have made sure QtSerialPort works with prior versions, including Qt 4.8.X. Here you can find the instructions for Qt 4 to get this installed for you:

- git clone git@gitorious.org:qt/qtserialport.git
- cd qtserialport
- qmake
- make
- sudo make install.

Then, you will need the following lines in your qmake project file if you happen to use qmake:

```
Qt 5: QT += serialport
Qt 4: COMFIG += serialport
```

Comment: Finally got together a solution. I actually ended up using `QSerialPortInfo` to validate a port before using it.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. I just needed something to validate that the serial port was actually plugged in before it tried to do anything with an open port. I did something slightly different that worked for what I'm doing.

Comment: What exactly *is* a `ResourceError`? I'm occasionally seeing it in the middle of some serial-port communication, but I'm still able to send and receive some data on the port. (My communications layer starts behaving badly, but it doesn't seem entirely broken--some valid packets still get through.)

Answer (score 2):

Using `QSerialPortInfo` will achieve the result:

```
bool MyClass::checkPort()
{
    QSerialPortInfo *portInfo = new QSerialPortInfo(ui->serialDevice->currentText());
    // ui->serialDevice being a combobox of available serial ports

    if (portInfo->isValid())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`isValid()` is now obsolete. `isBusy()` can be used instead as it will return `true` when you have opened the port and `false` when the port is no longer there (and you still have it open). This is also the case when `availablePorts()` keeps returning the non-existent, but opened port, because you are keeping the port in the list by having it opened.